# joda-time override date format and Chronology for a locale

Tags: java, date, jodatime

We have a website which displays dates using joda-time. Actually it works pretty well to display local date times for US, FR, etc.

We are currently facing an issue with Thaïland. When displaying the local date, Joda-time uses Buddhist Chronology. We would like to use the Gregorian. Is it possible to overwrite it ? 
Another thing is that we would like to use the date format dd/MM/YYYY when displaying local dates for Thaïland. Is it possible to set it globally for a locale ?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you displaying the date? Calling toString()?

Comment: My bad. I'm sorry. When displaying the page we use freemarker. A wrapper get the date and transform it to a freemarker date. I will look on it.
We use the annotation ?dateTime?string.short

Comment: How do you construct your `LocalDate`-instance? You can always specify the ISO-Chronology.

Comment: Hello. sorry I've been really busy. 
The ISO-Chronology is the one used (in debug mode I see this one on my date). 
It seems that Freemarker uses the standard java Calendar to display the dates.
With th_TH, Calendar automatically takes Buddhist Chronology